# Daterangepicker - unable to select today's date

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I used below code for date picker in my application. 
daterangepicker plugin used.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/jkenluv/z9tgdh7k/
```

**HTML**

```
<input class="form-control input-lg" id="tripOne" name="tripOne" />
```

**JS:**

```
var nowDate = new Date();
var today = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(), nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
var maxLimitDate = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear() + 1, nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

$('input[name="tripOne"]').daterangepicker({
"autoApply": true,
"autoUpdateInput": false,
"singleDatePicker": true,
"minDate": today,
"maxDate": maxLimitDate,
"opens": "left",
"locale": {
    format: 'DD MMM YYYY'
  }
}, function (start, end) {
  $("#tripOne").val(start.format('DD MMM YYYY'));
  $('#tripOne').parent().parent().removeClass('has-error');
});

$(function() {
    $('.calendar.right').show();
});
```

But, i cant able to select **'Today's date'** or **'already selected date'**. Which is mandatory for our requirement. Please let me know how to solve this issue?

Thanks

Thanks

Comment: Your code seems to work just fine! Where is the problem?

Comment: For ex: on load.. select 18th Feb (today's date).. it wont be clickable. But, if you select 19th.. it will work

Comment: I don't know why it's not working for you. But it's working for me. I can select today's date.

Comment: Hi.. After page loaded, you can select 18th Feb (today)..will value stored in input field??

Comment: Select 19th feb for example.. delete input feild manually. If you can able to select 19th feb again and date showing in input field??

Answer (score 2):

Not the most beautiful solution but you can alter daterangepicker.js and remove the following line in the 'hide' method:

```
if (!this.startDate.isSame(this.oldStartDate) || !this.endDate.isSame(this.oldEndDate))
```

It will work but you can never update daterangepicker.js. It should be better to overwrite the hide method.

Answer (score 0):

Please [read the doc](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#ex5)

> If you're using a date range as a filter, you may want to attach a
>   picker to an input but leave it empty by default. This example shows
>   how to accomplish that using the `autoUpdateInput` setting, and the
>   `apply` and `cancel` events.

So either you can remove `autoUpdateInput` line or you can set it to `true`.

```
"autoUpdateInput": false,
```

OR

```
"autoUpdateInput": true,
```

Comment: If i remove this... then onload.. i can able to see today's date.. But, our calendar input value have to trigger after user clicked input. Also, still i can able to click Today's or already selected date

Answer (score 0):

```
var nowDate = new Date();
  var today = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(), nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
  var maxLimitDate = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(), nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate()+360, 0, 0, 0, 0);

  $('input[name="tripOne"]').daterangepicker({
    "autoApply": true,
    "autoUpdateInput": false,
    "singleDatePicker": true,
    "minDate": today,
    "maxDate": maxLimitDate,
    "locale": {
        format: 'DD MMM YYYY'
    }
  },function(start) {
      $("#tripOne").val(start.format('DD MMM YYYY'));
      $('#tripOne').parent().parent().removeClass('has-error');
      setTimeout(function(){
          $('.daterangepicker').addClass('returnTripEndDatePicker');
          $('.departure--date').hide();
          $(".returnTripEndDatePicker").prepend("<div class='departure--date'>Select Return Date</div>");
          $( "#tripTwo" ).focus();
      },120);
      var returnTripStartDate = new Date(Date.parse(start));
      $(function() {
        $('.calendar.right').show();
      });
  });
  $('input[name="tripTwo"]').daterangepicker({
        "autoApply": true,
        "autoUpdateInput": false,
        "singleDatePicker": true,
        "minDate": today,
        "maxDate": maxLimitDate,
        "locale": {
            format: 'DD MMM YYYY'
        }
      },function(end) {
            $("#tripTwo").val(end.format('DD MMM YYYY'));
            $('#tripTwo').parent().parent().removeClass('has-error');
      });
  $('input[name="tripOne"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
        $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('DD MMM YYYY'));
      });
      $('input[name="tripTwo"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
        $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('DD MMM YYYY'));
      });
```

Comment: Hi Puhan... Thanks for your valuable comments. 90% works fine.

Comment: But, https://jsfiddle.net/jkenluv/z9tgdh7k/2/ please check this link.. After load.. today's date is not clickable.. if i select 19th feb and select next input date 19th. it works. But, not working only on 1st input today's date

Comment: Not able to understand. Could you plz let me know what do you mean by not clickable here?

Comment: Please click on fiddle link. 1) Click 1st input field, select today date. Will it select and show value on input?  2) On 1st input field, select 19th feb. Now, you can select 19th feb on 2nd input field also.  your logic works here. Is it possible to implement same logic on 1st input field? Thanks

Comment: Hi.. any solution pls?

Comment: Hi boss.. thanks for your reply.. I tried like this method. https://jsfiddle.net/jkenluv/z9tgdh7k/6/

Comment: What happens means.. On first click and select the date.. auto focus to next input is missing. Now.. we need select 2nd input date manually. If you come back to 1st input and select date again. now, autofocus will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
$("element1").datetimepicker({ maxDate: moment.endOf( 'day' ) })
$("element2").datetimepicker({ maxDate: moment.endOf( 'day' ) })
```

If you use `minDate` do the opposite

```
$("element1").datetimepicker({ minDate: moment.startOf( 'day' ) })
$("element2").datetimepicker({ minDate: moment.startOf( 'day' ) })
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below function after initialization of daterangepicker:

```
$('input[name="tripOne"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
        $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('DD MMM YYYY'));
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code can be used to fix the issue and keep the original script updatable, or load it from CDN:

```
drpDecorator($('input[class="date-input"]').daterangepicker({
        singleDatePicker: true,
        minYear: 1950,
        maxYear: parseInt(moment().format('YYYY'), 10),
        autoApply: true,
        autoUpdateInput: false,
        "showDropdowns": false,
        locale: {
            firstDay: 1,
            cancelLabel: 'Reset',
            format: 'MM/DD/YY'
        }
    }, function (chosen_date) {
        $(this)[0].element.val(chosen_date.format('MM/DD/YY'));
    })
)


function drpDecorator($dateInput) {
    if ($dateInput.length === 0) {
        return
    }
    const drp = $dateInput.data("daterangepicker");

    drp.hide = function (e) {
        if (!this.isShowing) return;

        //incomplete date selection, revert to last values
        if (!this.endDate) {
            this.startDate = this.oldStartDate.clone();
            this.endDate = this.oldEndDate.clone();
        }

        this.callback(this.startDate.clone(), this.endDate.clone(), this.chosenLabel);

        //if picker is attached to a text input, update it
        this.updateElement();

        $(document).off('.daterangepicker');
        $(window).off('.daterangepicker');
        this.container.hide();
        this.element.trigger('hide.daterangepicker', this);
        this.isShowing = false;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pwd5sLvf/

Answer (score 0):

I has the same problem. You need to edit the daterangepicker.js source code. The best solution is to define difference between cancel and apply. To do this I removed the following code from the hide method and pasted it into the clickApply method. And for the correct operation of autoApply and clicking on the current date, I added a check for an empty control value.

```
        //incomplete date selection, revert to last values
        if (!this.endDate) {
            this.startDate = this.oldStartDate.clone();
            this.endDate = this.oldEndDate.clone();
        }

        //if a new date range was selected, invoke the user callback function
        if (!this.startDate.isSame(this.oldStartDate) || ($(this.element).is(':text') && $(this.element).val() === '') || !this.endDate.isSame(this.oldEndDate))
            this.callback(this.startDate.clone(), this.endDate.clone(), this.chosenLabel);

        //if picker is attached to a text input, update it
        this.updateElement();
```